# Postfix statistics of each user, how do?

Tags: linux, email, smtp, debian, postfix-mta

Virtually use debian with postfix and mysql.
  I want to know how many emails for each user sends.

All statistics programs are generalities, I would like to know the specific number for each person who uses postfix.

**example**:
  I have 3 accounts postfix

```
  account1@abc.com
  account2@def.com
  account3@hfs.com
```

For each of them get statistics

```
  account1@abc.com
  sent 150email
  account2@def.com
  sent 425email
  account3@hfs.com
  sent 2email
  etc. ....
```

Is there a way?
  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [postfix-logwatch](http://logreporters.sourceforge.net/postfix-logwatch.1.html)

```
# Sample Usage
perl postfix-logwatch --nosummary --nodetail --limit envelopesenderdomains='2 1:10: 2:8:'  /var/log/maillog
# Command says Give 2 level output in which give top ten domains in level one( 1:10:) and top 8 users in each domain ie. level two ( 2:8: )
```

```
****** Detail (2) **********************************************************************************
   72488   Envelope sender domains -----------------------------------------------------------------
   14055      intranet.domain1.com
    6912         domain1-owner
    1203         owner
     486         cmowner
     370         sysaduser
     219         cowner
     185         towner
     175         autoowner
     167         cpanel-owner
                 ...
    8867      live.com
    8867         postman
    7635      *unknown
    7635         <>
    6172      domain2.com
     895         keybox
     588         autoearn
     480         autesting
     322         audit
     231         k_crawler
     120         user8
      94         mon
      80         orderadmin
```

Comment: for those on a debian system the script is '/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/postfix'
`/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/postfix --nosummary --nodetail --limit envelopesenderdomains='2 1:10: 2:8:'  /var/log/mail.log`